# URL rewriting of session cookies

Tags: cookies, session-management, url

I stumbled over this in the ASVS 3.0.1 ([V3](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard#V3:_Session_Management_Verification_Requirements).6). I wonder what this is, I couldn't find any meaningful explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems likely to refer to the practice simply writing session tokens into the URL as part of a GET request in the form of SomeAction.do;jsessionid=863F3D24DEFA?Id=19. This is obviously bad practice and not advised.

Comment: The full text of V3.6 reads _Verify that the session id is never disclosed in URLs, error messages, or logs. This includes verifying that the application does not support URL rewriting of session cookies._ Now that I think twice about it it seems plausible that your answer explains it pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what is meant without some kind of example, however I would speculate that this means, "Never store URL parameters in cookies." Doing so would potentially open a site up to lots of XSS vulnerabilities. If you're doing this with session variables, then a session could possibly be hijacked simply with a copied URL.